# PHP Output Multiple SQL Query Number of Results

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have five different SQL queries that I would like to return back the number of rows returned in a list. Basically I have a MySQL database and would like to show some statistics on how many records we have and how many of them have had information added. Examples of the queries are...

```
SELECT * FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_1` 
SELECT * FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_2` 
SELECT * FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_3` 
SELECT * FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_1` WHERE `field_30` <> ''
SELECT * FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_2` WHERE `field_60` <> ''
```

Which should return back the following output

```
Total Records Database 1: 12,548
Total Records Database 2: 9,835
Total Records Database 3: 5,916
Filled Out Records in Database 1: 567
Filled Out Records in Database 2: 681
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?  It's straight-forward to run a MySQL query from PHP and then count the results; knowing the specific issues you face in doing this can help you get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be *much* more efficient to have the database prepare a result containing just the count of rows, rather than preparing a complete set of ten thousand plus rows.

For example, to have the database return the results as shown in the question:

```
 SELECT CONCAT('Total Records Database 1: ',FORMAT(COUNT(1),0) AS txt 
   FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_1` 
  UNION ALL
 SELECT CONCAT('Total Records Database 2: ',FORMAT(COUNT(1),0) 
   FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_2`
  UNION ALL
 SELECT CONCAT('Total Records Database 3: ',FORMAT(COUNT(1),0)
   FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_3`
  UNION ALL
 SELECT CONCAT('Filled Out Records in Database 1: ',FORMAT(COUNT(1),0)
   FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_1` WHERE `field_30` <> ''
  UNION ALL
 SELECT CONCAT('Filled Out Records in Database 1: ',FORMAT(COUNT(1),0)
   FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_2` WHERE `field_60` <> ''
```

If you want to handle the labeling and formatting in the application layer, you could just return the counts in a single row:

```
 SELECT t1.cnt  AS t1_cnt
      , t2.cnt  AS t2_cnt
      , t3.cnt  AS t3_cnt
      , f1.cnt  AS f1_cnt
      , f2.cnt  AS f2_cnt
   FROM ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_1` ) t1
   JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_2` ) t2
   JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_3` ) t3
   JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_1` WHERE `field_30` <> '' ) f1
   JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM `ibf_ccs_custom_database_1` WHERE `field_60` <> '' ) f2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just build an array with key => value pairs for your row counts.  Something like this:

```
$db_queries = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM ibf_ccs_custom_database_1";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$db_queries['q1'] = $res->num_rows;

$query = "SELECT * FROM ibf_ccs_custom_database_2";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$db_queries['q2'] = $res->num_rows;

$query = "SELECT * FROM ibf_ccs_custom_database_3";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$db_queries['q3'] = $res->num_rows;

$query = "SELECT * FROM ibf_ccs_custom_database_1 WHERE field_30 <> ''";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$db_queries['q4'] = $res->num_rows;

$query = "SELECT * FROM ibf_ccs_custom_database_2 WHERE field_60 <> ''";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$db_queries['q5'] = $res->num_rows;

foreach($db_queries as $k => $v){
    echo $k, " contains ", $v, " rows.";
}
```